# Redirect to different page using a variable from the current page url in razor

Tags: razor, redirect

I've inherited a project that used to use razor (cshtml) to render pages. Users have bookmarked the old workflow that uses razor and I need to redirect them to the same page in the new workflow. The urls for the current pages use an id to indicate what entity is being shown. Like so:

`https://mywebsite.com/oldworkflow/253432`

where 253432 is the id of the entity they are viewing in the old workflow.

How do I grab that Id on the end and use it to redirect to the new workflow?

`https://mywebsite.com/newworkflow/253432`

Comment: While it can be done in code, the server redirection would be a better option IMO.  It would not require code changes to the original site that will significantly modify its behavior.  The server redirection also does not require the original site to be deployed any longer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not good enough with server redirection to implement it. So I'm in desperate need of an answer to this question.

Comment: Surely you are capable of performing a simple Google search.

Comment: Sure I can. But I don't know .NET well enough.

Comment: A server redirect would be implemented by the server, not .NET.   Assuming IIS, search for "IIS redirects" to start with.

Comment: Yeah I did. Is that not for for redirecting the whole website, not specific pages?